# Undo global STDERR -> STDOUT redirection

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, tty

I'm working on a script that ssh's into hosts and then sudo's to a privileged user. Since our hosts do not allow sudo with non-tty sessions, pseudo-tty is enabled.

pseudo-tty automatically redirects all STDERR output to STDOUT. This is causing a litany of issues for the project, as dependent libraries do not handle STDERR output well.

Is it possible to undo the STDERR -> STDOUT output redirect? In other words, is it possible to globally mandate that all STDERR output *not* be sent to STDOUT? I know it's possible to do on a per-command basis, but I'm looking for a way to do this that only has to be done once - ideally when ssh'ing to the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "undo" a redirection, but you can redirect somewhere else.

A "bare" redirection in a shell script (eg, `2>/dev/null`) on a line by itself will redirect stdout or stderr for the shell itself and so for all future commands the shell runs.

Comment: Yes you can. You can clone the file descriptors, then close entries 1 and 2 in PDT which correspond to `stdout` and `stderr`, Then add the cloned FD which will occupy the first entries in PDT which are not in use. (Freshly closed 1 and 2 entries). I think...

Comment: @TonyTannous: that does a new redirection, it doesn't undo a previous redirection.  You can't undo a redirection as the knowledge of where the fd used to go is lost after it is closed.  You can only guess at where it used to go and try to reopen it.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks :) I meant you can "restore" it for `stdin` and `stdout` for example as we know where their FD used to be in the PDT. But I agree with your comment.